On the "Charge fractionalization"
In the "Mirror symmetry" book by Hori, Vafa, et al. (which is available on the web), the observation is made (starting at 15.5.2, and directly up to 15.5.3) which can be summarized as follows.
Let us consider the $\mathbb CP^{N-1}$-model realized by the $U(1)$ gauge theory with N chiral superfields of charge $1$. The authors work semi-classically, show that the effective $\theta$-angle $\theta_\text{eff}$ of a soliton looks like a step-function, and conclude that there is no long range force.
So far so good. Or, more precisely, not completely. But, anyway, after that, they claim the following:

"Thus, the $\Phi_i$-particle exists as a particle state in the quantum Hilbert space. From the classical story, we expect that these states constitute the fundamental representation of the group $SU(N)$. Note that $SU(N)$ is not quite the same as the classical global symmetry group $SU(N)/\mathbb Z_N$. The symmetry group of the quantum theory is not $SU(N)/\mathbb Z_N$ but its universal covering group. Such a phenomenon is common in quantum field theories (known as charge fractionalization). In the present case this happens because there appeared a state transforming nontrivially under the “overlap” $\mathbb Z_N$ of $SU(N)$ and the gauge group, $U(1)$. Whether such a thing happens or not depends on the gauge dynamics. If the $Φ_i$ particles were confined (as in the case without $\operatorname{arg}(σ)-v_{\mu}$ coupling), there would not be a state charged under the U(1) gauge group, and therefore all the states would be neutral under $\mathbb Z_N = SU(N) \cap U(1)$. In that case, the global symmetry group would remain as $SU(N)/\mathbb Z_N$."

This is all non-clear for me, or, more precisely, the only phrase that is tolerable is the one about $SU(n)/\mathbb Z_n$. Even more precisely (though, a bit tautologically), I can formulate the questions as:
a) Why the symmetry group of the quantum thing is $SU(N)$-itself? This should be clear after someone will introduce to me the aforementioned state transforming non-trivially under the group $SU(N) \cap U(1)$.
b) What does the existence of the state from b) has to do with the absence of the confinement?
This is almost for sure based on my lack of a general physical background and some misunderstaning. I really apologize for this particular type of question (I am a mathematician, and am currently trying to understand some physics) but expect some more to come soon.
